# CosmosDB - Consistency levels for a Multiregion collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a `USER` collection which stores user information. Every item will these 3 fields:

```
-UserID
-Username
-Email
```

If in the future I need to make this collection available across different regions I understand there are 5 different consistency levels (strong, bounded staleness, session, consistent prefix, and eventual consistency). If I want to guarantee that two users in two different regions do not create the same user (with either the same `userid` or `username` or `email`) at the same time is my only option then strong consistency?

A follow-up question; if I set this collection to be strong, do all my other collections also have to be strong or can I set the consistency level of different collections to different levels (For e.g `USER` collection is strong and `POSTS` are eventual)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-master can only be configured to have a weaker consistency than strong. So, CosmosDB cannot stop two different regions create the same user concurrently but it gives you the ability to do conflict resolution When such a conflict occurs, you can resolve the conflict by using different conflict resolution policies.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/conflict-resolution-policies

You can configure the default consistency level on your Azure Cosmos account at any time. The default consistency level configured on your account applies to all Azure Cosmos databases and containers under that account. All reads and queries issued against a container or a database use the specified consistency level by default.

Consistency level can be set per request, which overrides the default consistency level set at the account level. But the client side override can only be weaker than the default consistency level configured at the account level.

If you need collection specific default consistency level then you should put collections with the same default consistency level needs in one account.